# Best way to create a service that doesn't die.(like WhatsApp or Facebook)

Tags: android, android-service

I have tried till now
- start sticky
- alarm to restart service
- on task removed start the service 
- use job service (has latency and executes task slow)

Is there a proper method to make an infallible background service like the popular apps?

Comment: How do you know those apps have such a service?

Comment: @Tim Casteljins I have observed that these services aren't killed even in doze and aggressive doze mode. If they are then they are restarted and I have never missed a msg from WhatsApp so I think they have a pretty good way of keeping it alive.

Comment: What makes you think whatsapp uses a background service to handle incoming messages?

Comment: Atleast they don't die randomly

Comment: what doesn't die randomly?

Comment: The services of most of the popular apps don't die randomly. If os kills them then they are restarted and I want to know how do they do that.

Comment: coming back to my first comment: how do you know they have such services?

Comment: Development options>> running services

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Creating a background service that "does not die" is not possible in android.

You can create a service and take certain measures to have it running as much as possible, but the OS **will** kill it at times and your service will not be running until the OS decides to restart it (in case it is a sticky service).

Things you can do:

- Make the service sticky, so that it will be restarted by the OS after the OS kills it. It is impossible to predict when it will be restarted. It can be almost instant, it can take seconds, minutes, hours, or more.
- Start the service when you open the app.
- Start the service when the app is upgraded, using the `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` broadcast.
- Start the service when the device is (re)booted, using the `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `REBOOT` broadcasts.
- Override `onTaskRemoved` in the service, to schedule a restart of the service in case the user swipes away your app from the list of recent apps.
- Use FCM to periodically send messages to the app with an instruction to start the service in case it is not running anymore.

You can never have a 100% uptime, but this will get you close.

Comment: I have done all except the last one. Can you also tell me how to manage it in doze mode in 7.0?

Comment: Doze will not *kill* your service. It will however apply certain restrictions, such as no internet access. You can read all about it in the doze&standby docs

Comment: I have read that. But I don't know why but my service is dead in doze mode. That's why I tried job scheduler and that is very slow and unpredictable

Comment: In any case it will be unpredictable, your service will have downtime and you will never know when or for how long. Apps are not meant to be able to run 24/7, it is a pity for us developers, but good for the users and phone batteries

Comment: I have had 3 2 star ratings because of this. And this problem is compounded by the fact people have these Chinese phones with custom roms that have their own task killers and security centers

Comment: Task killers and similar are a whole other story. Some devices/manufactureres just ruin things. You cannot avoid it. Best you can do is point your users to the settings and ask them to put your app on the whitelist of such task killers

Comment: I am too annoyed with Chinese phones like Xiaomi/Oppo/Vivo  just can't keep my tasks running as low as for an hour. White Listing is good at some point but asking permissions on different models and guide the novice users how to set those permissions with different UI settings is too difficult as every model these companies make have different UI interface and settings hidden in lump corner of it. Should google protect Android OS from tampering, YES YES YES

Comment: Sir i am using `START_STICKY` but after boot complete the broadcast is not listing the `BOOT_COMPLETED`

Answer (score 5):

A background service, if not visible by the user will always be killed earlier or later by the Android system. It is the way memory management work.

If you really need to make a service continously run, you need to show a permanent notification to the user (like when you are using a radio app or a music player app).

What whatsapp and facebook probably do is to wake up the app remotely with any sort of messaging such as Firebase Cloud Messaging (ex-Google Cloud Messaging) or using Broadcast Receiver on certains events... But it surely isn't en ever going on service.

Read this part of Android documentation to better understand this:
[Service Process Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle).

As you can see, to give priority to your service process you will need to start it in foreground and pass it an Ongoing Notification using  startForeground(int id, Notification notification). 
Use setOngoing(true) in your NotificationBuilder to set a Notification as an Ongoing one: [setOngoing(boolean b) doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)").

Finally you usually want to add action in your Ongoing Notification (such as Player controls or the possibility to close the notification and hence your service when memory will be collected)

Here a full sample code:

```
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small_icon)
        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        //.addAction(android.R.drawable.close_service,"Close", closeServiceIntent)
        .build();
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried that too. But users have complained that they don't like the icon in the status bar. Any way to remove the icon?

Comment: no you can not remove the icon from a foreground service

Comment: nope, either the user know your app is running or the memory will be used for the apps in foreground which are what the user really want to use at a specific moment

Answer (score -2):

It's not a good idea, check out [this article](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/). Using a service in this case is not a good approach.

Comment: In what case? You don't even know what his case is

Comment: In any case creating a everlasting service that doesn't die is not a good idea, is it?

Comment: I would argue that depends on the use case

Comment: My app watches the clipboard and when a user copies a word you get a pop up with the meaning of the word. And I think an infallible background service fits here.